# What is the formal way to denote a fraction of a fraction?

Tags: article-writing

I need to write a paper and it's not clear which is correct: $\frac{x/y}{z}$ or $\frac{\frac{x}{y}}{z}$, or possibly some other alternative.

Comment: Usually the 2nd one is used, to my knowledge.

Comment: Whichever is more readable in context. If the expression is in-line, $\frac{x/y}z$ is almost certainly preferable, and this may well also be tha case if it’s part of a more compicated displayed expression. If it’s a displayed expression by itself, the choice is up to you; for me it would depend on the audience and on what I was saying about the expression, but *ceteris paribus* I’d tend to prefer the first version. I do not agree with @Colbi.

Comment: Perhaps one could also say something like $\dfrac{5}{6}\div \dfrac{6}{5}$

Comment: Why not $\frac{1}{z}\frac{x}{y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are 'correct', at least in the sense that nobody will argue that either is somehow 'mathematically wrong'.

However, the latter, $\frac{x/y}{z}$, definitely looks a lot nicer in most circumstances, especially if you're typesetting it in-line like I just did.

If you don't typeset it in-line, then you can perhaps play around. To me, $$\frac{\frac{x}{y}}{z}$$ is not *too* bad, particularly if the numerator is long and involves more than one term, like $$\frac{g(x)+\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}.$$ But you can also play around: you can use `\dfrac` in the numerator: `\frac{g(x)+\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}`, which gives
$$\frac{g(x)+\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}.$$
The result may be more readable. However, `\frac{\dfrac{x}{y}}{z}` produces
$$\frac{\dfrac{x}{y}}{z}$$ which certainly looks horrible.

The point stands: use what looks best. Of your two choices, $\frac{x/y}{z}$ is the answer.

Comment: *Footnote:* this reminds me of a funny story about Barry Mazur annoying Serge Lang. See [this MathOverflow post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18593/what-are-the-worst-notations-in-your-opinion/18606#18606) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The *"of"*  can be symbolically replaced by multiplication.

$\dfrac{x}{y} $ of $\dfrac{1}{z} $ , like half of one third is one sixth.

Comment: Definitely not, except possibly in a discussion of how to teach fractional arithmetic to elementary school students.

Comment: That's what I was taught in school.